# Tesseract OCR python code outputting gibberish or nothing

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am learning how to use the Tesseract OCR package to read an image and display the characters in the image.

However, when I run my code, the output does not display anything, or it displays random characters that are not in the image. Please let me know what might be going on.

```
h,w,c=image.shape
boxes=pytesseract.image_to_boxes(image)
for i in boxes.splitlines():
    i=i.split(' ')
    image=cv2.rectangle(image,(int(i[1]),h-int(i[2]))
                        ,(int(i[3]),h-int(i[4])),(0,255,0),2)

dict=pytesseract.image_to_data(image,output_type=Output.DICT)
keys=list(dict.keys())
boxes=len(dict['text'])
date= '^(0[1-9]| [12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d\d$'
for i in range(boxes):
    if int(float(dict['conf'][i]))>60:
        (x,y,w,h)=(dict['left'][i],dict['top'][i],dict['width'][i],dict['height'][i])
        image=cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        if re.match(date,dict['text'][i]):
            (x,y,w,h)=(dict['left'][i],dict['top'][i],dict['width'][i],dict['height'][i])
            image=cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

config1=r'--oem 3 --psm 8'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image,config=config1))
cv2.imshow('image',image)
```

Comment: What is your purpose exactly ? You seem to want to display the text from the full image, but you process the image resulting from last iteration among boxes. Also, could you provide a reproducible sample of code? The type of image object is not known.

Comment: Also, what is the result of simply `print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))` , without all your code above?